# Query multiple XML nodes under a root Element

Tags: xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

How to query all XML nodes that are part of an element node?

I want to query the data under similar_books tag of all book tags, but I am getting only first book tag data.
URL for XML response is https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&title=DUNE

Structure is like this:

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
         <Request>
         <book>

       <Similar_books>

            <book>
            </book>

              <book>
             </book>

             <book>
             </book>

             <book>
             </book>

         </Similar_books>

              <book>
           <Request> 
        </GoodreadsResponse>
```

my code looks like this .

```
search.Text = "";
       var xdoc=  XDocument.Load("https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&title=" + title.Text);

     var S =   xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//similar_books");
      var b =  xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//book");


        XElement search_result =
      ( from xFi in S.Elements()
       select xFi).FirstorDefault();
        if (search_result != null)
        {
            BOOK_URL.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(search_result.Element("image_url").Value));

            search.Text =
                     "Title: " + search_result.Element("title").Value + "\n"+  "Average Ratings:  " + search_result.Element("average_rating").Value + "\n" +
                     "ISBN: " + search_result.Element("isbn").Value + "\n" +
                    "PUBLICATION YEAR: " + search_result.Element("publication_year").Value + "\n";

        }

        else
        {
            search.Text = "Found Nothing";
        }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Xamarin Forms?   And you need to post the code you have already tried, and perhaps give a more explicit example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: i m using Xdocument and XPath to query xml tags in xamarin forms but ended up getting data of only first tag.

Comment: we can't tell you what you are doing wrong if you don't show us what you are doing.  Please post your code

Comment: sorry for incomplete question. i have posted the code!

Answer (score 0):

this XPath expression works for me

```
/GoodreadsResponse/book/similar_books/book
```

Note that the "sample" XML in your original post is NOT the same structure as the ACTUAL XML, which is probably why my earlier response was not working.

- "similar_books", not "Similar_books"
- "Request" is not the parent node of "books", it is a sibling